# Best way to get all possible attributes of a kinetic node object

Tags: kineticjs

What is the best way to get all possible attributes a Kinetic shape?
Can have programatically ?

`getAttrs()` only returns an object literal with the properties that already have been set. For Now I have been using the objects prototype getters and setters to determine the attributes. Is using a JSdoc style way better to determine them ? (getting them from comments)

Answer (score 1):

The myShape.attrs object holds the shape's properties.

However, myShape.attrs is not pre-populated with all the possible properties a shape can have.

**So, There's no programmatic way to get all possible values of a Kinetic object.**

You can use .getOwnPropertyNames to iterate the myShape.attrs object's existing properties.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myKineticShape.attrs).forEach(
    function(propName, index, array) {
        console.log(propName+"=="+myKineticShape.attrs[propName]);
    }
);
```